# What is pradosh kaal/ pradosh kaalam?

Tags: practice, astrology, time

What time is referred to as pradosh kalam? I’m not asking about pradosh vrat. Pradosh kalam is a particular time period in every day. I want to know which time period exactly. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Pradosh Kaal starts after sunset and lasts for 3 muhurtas after that (approximately 2 hours and 24 minutes). ~ [Ref1](https://www.drikpanchang.com/festivals/lakshmipuja/festivals-lakshmipuja-timings.html?year=2021), [Ref2](https://www.amarujala.com/photo-gallery/astrology/diwali-2021-laxmi-puja-muhurat-timing-kab-hai-laxmi-puja-muhurat-laxmi-puja-time-diwali-laxmi-ganesh-puja-timings-lakshmi-puja-in-delhi-noida-mumbai-up-mp-and-other-cities)

Comment: Can you provide the Reference please?

Comment: I think pradosh Kala is time upto 72 min after sunset.